# Google Datastore Query Admin erases data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After the new interface update from Google, if I go to console.google.com, under Cloud datastore -> query, and update any value of an object from there, the entire object values are erased, leaving a record with an ID, and all its properties overwritten with empty values.
Is this happening only to me?

Comment: Not just you, i cant edit entities through the console UI now (worked 2 days ago) . How long has this been happening? The are deploying a new console version and you might be getting some glitch from the new version.

Comment: Same thing, this is approx. a 2-day old issue.

Comment: if this really is an issue (I'd say it is with at least 2 ppl reporting it), it would be more appropriate to report it on Google's issue tracker, on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/